# Create stored procedures from create and select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to create a  stored procedures in wich i have to create a table from select  statements in which I have to insert parameters.
Here is my query :

```
CREATE TABLE DBL_JW AS
      SELECT * FROM (  
      SELECT m.IDM,  
            m2.IDM AS dups_key  
      FROM members_tbl m  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN members_tbl m2  
      ON ( m.IDM != m2.IDM  
      AND m.DBIRTH = m2.DBIRTH  
      AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(m.SNAME,m2.SNAME) > 90
      AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(m.FNAME,m2.FNAME) > 95))  
      Where dups_key IS NOT NULL;
```

I've tried to write this stored procedures :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JW_DBL_POT 
(
  P_SNAME IN NUMBER 
, P_FNAME IN NUMBER 
, P_RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN P_RC
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
      CREATE TABLE DBL_JW AS
      SELECT * FROM (  
      SELECT m.IDM,  
            m2.IDM AS dups_key  
      FROM members_tbl m  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN members_tbl m2  
      ON ( m.IDM != m2.IDM  
      AND m.DBIRTH = m2.DBIRTH  
      AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(m.SNAME,m2.SNAME) > P_SNAME  
      AND utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(m.FNAME,m2.FNAME) > P_FNAME ))  
      Where dups_key IS NOT NULL;  
END JW_DBL_POT;
```

I'm facing this errors :
 - PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “CREATE”
even removing the  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`  instruction, I have the same error. How can I manage it ?
Thx

Comment: You aren't passing [a string argument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#CJACGJJG) to `execute immediate`. What is supposed to go into `P_RC`? Why would you want to create a table at runtime anyway; or a table that is duplicating data in other tables (and will then go stale)?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely had to store this information in a table, it sounds like it would only be needed temporarily as part of the process of fixing the data.

Rather than creating a table each time you run the code and then dropping it after you're done with it (which is what I assume your plan is for this table!), why not create a Global Temporary Table (GTT) once, and then use that to store data on a per session basis - ie. only your session can see the data that's been stored there during that session.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion; I have no idea. So how do I use to write Global Temporary Table ?

Comment: I would highly recommend you read up about GTTs. [Try this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) to start off with. There's plenty more in the documentation.